# zip dict.items() of mutiple dicts in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, zip, items

I think this should be easy but can't find a simple and elegant solution.
I have this:

```
l = [{1: 1, 2: 2},
     {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}]
```

I want this:

```
l = [((1, 1), ('a', 'a')),
     ((2, 2), ('b', 'b'))]
```

How do I zip together the items of multiple dicts in a list?

Comment: Something like `zip(*map(dict.items, l))`. Note though that the order of keys in dictionaries may change.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, also works with OrderedDict to keep order. Please post as an answer.

Comment: @barrios Does the order of our output list matter?

Comment: Yes it does. I wondered if the same effect can be achieved with a comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

#### Python 3

In Python 3, `dict.items` returns a `dict_items` object. To prevent this, you can turn them all into tuples by doing:

```
list(zip(*map(dict.items, l)))
```

Where `zip(*<iterable>)` is expanding the iterable into arguments of `zip` and then `zip` will zip the arguments into tuples (effectively turning all the values into tuples).

This, however, builds multiple lists in the process very redundantly. This can be avoided by doing:

```
list(map((lambda d: tuple(d.items())), l))
# Or with multiple maps:
list(map(tuple, map(dict.items, l))))
```

Which is, arguably, more intuitive, but does use a `lambda` or multiple maps so is less efficient for smaller lists of dictionaries.

#### Python 2

In Python 2, `dict.items` returns a `list`. If you don't specifically need a tuple over a list, keeping them as a list is fine, and `map(dict.items, l)` would suffice.

Here, you can do the same as above (omitting `list(...)` as `zip` returns a list:

```
zip(*map(dict.items, l))
```

You can also simply map `tuple`.

```
map(tuple, map(dict.items, l))
# Or with a lambda:
map((lambda d: tuple(d.items())), l)
```